# When does an exclamation mark come midway in a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, style

In [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), I found the following sentence:

> Specifically, Hello, which was `U+0048` `U+0065` `U+006C` `U+006C`
>   `U+006F`, will be stored as `48 65 6C 6C 6F`, which, **behold!** is
>   the same as it was stored in ASCII, and ANSI, and every OEM character
>   set on the planet.
>   *(emphasis added)*

The exclamation mark appears in the middle of a sentence, and from the context, it clearly doesn't end the preceding sentence and start a new one. Now consider below:

> 1. Behold this! It is a carrot.
> 2. Behold this! for it is a carrot.

It looks like `1.` consists of two sentences, and `2.` consists of a single sentence, with the exclamation mark.

Are both these usages correct? What is the rule regarding when an exclamation mark ends a sentence, and when it doesn't?

Comment: You'd think he'd fix his article, since it's been out of date almost as long as it's been online and people still refer to it in 2015...

Answer (score 1):

Generally an exclamation mark means the end of a sentence. However, in a few unusual cases it can be used for emphasis in the middle of a sentence, like in your first example, where it has a slightly comedic, overdramatic effect as it imitates Biblical language.

See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25232/exclamation-marks-in-the-middle-of-a-sentence for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an exclamation point marks the end of a sentence, when used correctly.  The example did not use it correctly.  The punctuation doesn't seem to flow properly; however, we can discern what the writer meant.

How could he have properly used the exclamation point, and still placed it in mid-sentence?  Like this:

Hello, which was....wll be stored as....which (Behold!) is the same as...

Thus the exclamation is a complete, punctuated sentence, encapsulated as a parenthetical remark within the main sentence.

As for your carrot examples: #1 is good; #2 is not. Especially when you start with "behold", the exclamation makes a complete sentence.  Or you could try "Behold—a carrot!

Comment: The carrot example is taken from Rowan Atkinson's stand-up comedy act "Amazing Jesus". :)